# pandas dataframe replace multiple substring of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below the code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['$5,756', '3434', '$45', '1,344']})

pattern = ','.join(['$', ','])

df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('$|,', '', regex=True)
print(df['A'])
```

What I am trying to remove every occurrence of '$' or ','... so I am trying to replace with blank..

But its replacing only ,

Output I am getting

```
0    $5756
1     3434
2      $45
3    1344$
```

it should be

```
0    5756
1     3434
2      45
3    1344
```

What I am doing wrong

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have integer-like numbers an easy option is to remove all but digits `\D`, then you don't have to deal with other special regex characters like `$`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
      A
0  5756
1  3434
2    45
3  1344
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['$5,756', '3434', '$45', '1,344']})
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('[$,]', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      A
0  5756
1  3434
2    45
3  1344
```

The problem is that the character `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (emphasis mine):

> **$**
> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end
> of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline.
> foo matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression foo$
> matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for foo.$ in
> 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in MULTILINE mode;
> searching for a single $ in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one
> just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.mode;
> searching for a single $ in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one
> just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.

So you need to *escape* the character or put it inside a character class.

As an alternative use:

```
df['A'].str.replace('\$|,', '', regex=True)  # note the escaping \
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['$5,756', '3434', '$45', '1,344']})
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('$', '', regex=True)
print(df['A'])
```